# MySql Connection Error using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, socket.io, nodemon

> Connection lost: The server closed the connection

With node_modules mysql using Node.js.
I have installed npm's nodemon modules to continiously monitor my node.js application and restart the server when it crashese still when the sever crashes the application does not restart on its own.

[image: Sample image is uploaded below with error description.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Searching lots of sites & implementing codes i have successfully resolved above error. For this I used mysqlpool. Code is below with description.

First of all you declare the connection like this :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var mysqlPool  = mysql.createPool({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "username",
    password: "password",
    database :"databasename",
    port:3306

});
```

Now your connection configuration has been successfully created & used like this :

```
var strQuery = "SELECT * FROM userdetails"; //here store sql query in strQuery variable.
     mysqlPool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            if(err) throw err;
            connection.query(strQuery, function(err, rows) {
                if(err) {
// if error occures goes here.

                    connection.end(); // if error occured closed the connection
                    console.error(err);                   
                    return;
                }
//If no error here you get your query output.

    console.log(rows[0].User_name); //retrieved  username & print into console log or you can also retrived any rows like this.

                connection.end();// After performing the operation then closed the connection.
            });
        });
```

Comment: This helped me out.
As of now, you get a warning for end() will become deprecated. Using  connection.release() will do the truck just fine.
For more info: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#pooling-connections

Answer (score 1):

Nodemon will restart the application only if any changes are made in any module or file !

Comment: I am not modifying any module

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to the `wait_timeout` server variable. When there is no data going through the connection for that many seconds, the server will drop the connection. You could raise the setting, but you run the risk of having more idle connections it has to cope with, and eventually you will hit the timeout again anyway.

The best solution would be for the client connection to be re-established when this happens, and that doesn't seem to be supported out of the box, but you might be able to implement this yourself: https://www.exratione.com/2013/01/nodejs-connections-will-end-close-and-otherwise-blow-up/

Another solution could be to periodically (before the timeout is up) do a simple query like `SELECT 1` to keep your connection alive.

Comment: Still i get same error "The server closed the connection"

Comment: "it still doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything... Update your post with code, details what you have done, etc.

Comment: In connection file I recreate the connection as you mention in your previous post. My code sample in below link: http://jsfiddle.net/Sanjay_kewat/xttUW/1/

Comment: Seems to me you have blindly copied over two solutions (one for MySQL, one for Redis) from that article rather than understanding, picking, adapting and integrating what you need.

Comment: I want to authenticate(simply perform authentication) the user's based on their credetials using mysql. My complete code working fine but after some hours around 10-12 hr. the server automatically closed the connection." I think this happen when the server was idle.". i am not able to understand how resolve the issues.

Comment: & I only used mysql for Database connectivity.